# Visual Basic Label Spacing

Tags: vb.net

I am Writing a program where I display sentences with specific options to select from. For example, I will have a label saying "The current car I drive is a" and 3 separate labels after saying *Ford* *Dodge* *Honda* *etc.*. Based on which label the user clicks, the others will be set to invisible and the selected label will move so the sentence displays like a full sentence without any spacing issues. I am using onclick, label.location = new point(0, 0) which works fine. However, in the program I have many different sentences with many options to chose from and it is very time consuming to find the new points of each label and change them. I was wondering if there is any way to set a standard space between all labels so I would not need to set new points at all.

Comment: Since you're eliminating the unselected ones after you pick one, why not just kill the whole line and replace the entire sentence with just one complete label?

Comment: Perhaps you should develop a usercontrol that consists of a label and a dynamic array of options.  You would code it once for the coords on that one user control, then it's reusable anywhere

Comment: You might want to consider replacing the three labels with a single ComboBox aligned in the proper place in the sentence. That way the user can pick from any number of choices without you needing any code to move the selected text.

Comment: A [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would arrange everything automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

```
rightLabel.Location= New Point(leftLabel.Right,leftLabel.Top)
```

Or you could use one label with the text "The current car %Who% drives is a %Make% ." then use the replace command:

```
labe.Text.Replace("%Who%","Fred")
label.Text.Replace("%Make%","Honda")
```

This way you could have one auto-sizing label, yet change its text easily.